# Basic automatic SEO on many domains

Tags: seo, automation

The web in company I work in has many language mutations (and associated domains).

Plan is to automate basic SEO on them. I will program it, colleagues will do data preparation for my code (searching data sources, etc.). First draft is, it will update each month, us doing some checks/updates if necessary.

Our current web site is mostly static.  It changes slowly or not at all.

Now, I am not SEO guy so can I ask for some guidelines?

From what I know, my best guess is auto-taking localized keywords from google-analytics and put them in image filenames, alt tags, keywords_meta, etc. randomly combined.

Is it right? Is there something else we can concentrate on?

Comment: That sounds like a plan to fail to me.   A big part of SEO is user experience these days. Automating content production based on keywords and domains was a successful SEO strategy five years ago, but it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important factors for the SEO is the exact **relevant content**, keywords, tags, images, etc. It would be a bad idea to put the keywords & tags randomly, because Google will find out that you are **introducing one thing with different or even contradictory definitions!** Google would penalize your website for this behavior.

In addition to that, irrelevant contents will disappoint your users and force them to **close your page or click on "BACK"** after viewing just one page (called bounce rate). This will kill your website's SEO because it tells search engines that they have **made a mistake** by referring visitors to your website!

Remember : **Search Engines love to please their users!**

One simple reason : *They need users trust to come back again!*

Also you need sufficient content, products, pages, etc, as well as people who have attraction to your content. You can't succeed with a few pages talking about things so common that they can be found everywhere, or even such rare subjects that no one will show interest in them.

You may need a living online market that attracts people and build trust over time.

Remember: **SEO is a time and energy consuming matter and it isn't wise to try shortcuts!**

If you need a quick reference of SEO Success Factors may [this table](https://searchengineland.com/seotable) and [this article](https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo) help you.

Comment: @JirkaJustra > Please accept this answer if it suits you.